# In Jython, How do I print a sentence with a float, which has a percentage symbol without a space between the number and symbol?

Tags: jython

This is a shortened version of my function. My function is: `def data(number):` When you enter the number it'll end up showing a percentage as a float and some text behind it.

The next line is: `print "total is: ", float(number), "%"`

Which prints:

```
>>> data(22)
total is:  22.0 %
```

What I want to do is remove the space between the 22.0 and the %, so the result looks like this instead `

```
>>> data(22)
total is:  22.0%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the comma-delimited expressions that follows `print` will be separated by a space.  One way to get control over that spacing is to use a format string.  For example:

```
def data(number):
    print "total is %s%%" % float(number)
```

The `%s` in the format string becomes the string value of `float(number)` and the `%%` in the format string becomes a literal `%` character.

But you might also want to look into `str.format()`.  There is a comparison between old-style format strings and new-style `str.format()` strings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format).